# how to converting sting into dateobject for date comparison?

Tags: python

I am facing trouble while converting string into dateobject in python. 
I want to convert string '10 JAN 2016" to dateobject so that i can compare it to the present date and get the time difference.

I tired but i am getting formatting error.What is the solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#) module.

```
import datetime
date = datetime.datetime.strptime('10 jan 2016`,'%d %b %Y').date()
difference_in_dates = date - datetime.date.today() #this returns a timedelta object
```

Use [`datetime.timedelta`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects) objects for comparison.

You can look up the documentation about the formats (%d, %m, etc.) [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior)

Answer (score -1):

You need to use a valid format.

Try looking here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior

```
dt = '10 JAN 2016'
dtime = datetime.datetime.strptime(dt, "theformat")
```